# DAX Excel Function

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

i have 2 columns ( `Total Planned Cost [CP] & Rolling Actual Cost` ) As    in below Pic

[image: Data]

i need Formula to calculate

IF( `(Total Planned Cost [CP] - Rolling Actual Cost`) <0 )

IF True ( `Total Planned Cost [CP] - Rolling Actual Cost`)

IF False ( 0 )

Comment: You essentially already typed out the formula you need.. Just replace your textual representations of the cells you are wanting with the cell reference - something we can't even do since you didn't include the headers on your screen shot.

Comment: sorry but i need to calculate it in power pivot in DAX in Caculation Area

Answer (score 0):

If `Total Planned Cost [CP]` was `B4`, and `Rolling Actual Cost` was `B5`, then your formula would look like:

```
=If(B4-B5<0, B4-B5, 0)
    ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^  ^
        |      |    |
        |      | Value if False
        |      |
        |  Value if true
        |
    Statement to check
```

Comment: No no i have these data in power pivot and i want to calculate it in DAX in calculation area

Answer (score 0):

```
Balance =

IF(
    'YourTableName'[Total Planned Cost [CP]] < 0,
    'YourTableName'[Total Planned Cost [CP]] - 'YourTableName'[Rolling Actual Cost],
    0
)
```